# mvc missing in Virtual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015

my issue here is that when I try to open an MVC 5 project on Visual Studio 2015 (enterprise), but it seems like I don't have MVC at all.
[image: When I open a new project that is what I get]

I tried to modify the application:
by adding a Microsoft web developer tool.

but it seems like that wasn't helpful.

that is what I suppose to get:
[image: demonstration of the expected windows.]

All other solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, while installing `VS 2015` you haven't installed `Web developer tools`. Try, re-installing visual studio again and check or select `Web developer tools`

Answer (score 0):

Install plugin directly from www.asp.net/mvc site

Comment: Have you tried clicking on mvc. It might give you the mvc5 option afterwards

Comment: where exactly? on the web page or the project's window?

Comment: inside 4.5.2 template box where mvc is written in the attached screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have installed these Tools via Extensions and Updates. Install these two tools [Microsoft ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2f8a7e60-2e6b-4220-b334-26d1e60ec54c) and [Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935).

You can install them by downloading from these URLs that I provided you and you can install them via Visual Studio with these steps:

**Visual Studio** > **Tools** > **Extensions and Updates** > **Online** > **... and search for these two tools and install them**.

Comment: yes I know I already did install them. it just seems like its not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe is simple and trivial but have you tried to install **ASP.NET Project Templates** from Visual Studio Gallery... you can find them [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9402d38e-2a85-434e-8d6a-8fc075068a42).